# Upcasting and Downcasting in c#

Tags: c#, casting

I have a setup like this:

```
public class PseudoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts {get; set;}

    public PseudoContext()
    {
        Accounts = new PseudoDbSet<Account>();
    }
}

public class PseudoDbSet<T> : DbSet<T> {}
```

So at runtime, `Accounts` should be of type `PseudoDbSet<Account>`?

When I try to access `Accounts` via `DbSet<Account> accountsSet = context.Accounts;`, I cannot downcast it to via `var tempSet = (PseudoDbSet<Account>)accountsSet`, I get the following runtime exception:

> Test method RoleManagerTest.PseudoContextTest.Add_ValidAccount_AccountAdded threw exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet 1[RoleManager.Models.Account]' to type 'RoleManager.Models.PseudoDbSet 1[RoleManager.Models.Account]

Why is that?

Edited to include some more information.

Comment: "InvalidCastException" is not a compiler error, nor is there any casting occurring there.. please include the *actual* error message and/or failure indicators.

Comment: Here it is:
`Test method RoleManagerTest.PseudoContextTest.Add_ValidAccount_AccountAdded threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet 1[RoleManager.Models.Account]' to type 'RoleManager.Models.PseudoDbSet 1[RoleManager.Models.Account]'.`

The casting happens while trying a `var tempSet = (PseudoDbSet<Account>)accountsSet`.

Comment: Sounds more like it's going in reverse and you're trying to case some unknown DbSet to PseudoDbSet, which might fail. Keep in mind none of this is known at compile time.

Comment: @Andreas Müller thanks for the hint, I updated the question.

Comment: @AndreasMüller Nope, the changes are indeed in the question :)

Comment: @Thaoden Alright. That's good. i'll remove the obsolete comments now

Comment: Sounds like someone has written to the property (the `set` accessor is `public` - why?) after the instance constructor ran. They put another instance in there, it seems. PS! A class declaration with parenthesis `()` should not be legal.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In the code, the class declaration has no parantheses, it's a typo here (but thanks for the hint).
As for the problem, I think I found it (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example code:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{

    public class DbSet<T> { }

    public class Account { }

    public class PseudoContext
    {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts {get; set;}

        public PseudoContext()
        {
            Accounts = new PseudoDbSet<Account>();
        }
    }

    public class PseudoDbSet<T> : DbSet<T> {}

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PseudoContext ct = new PseudoContext();
            PseudoDbSet<Account> db = (PseudoDbSet<Account>)ct.Accounts;

            Console.WriteLine(typeof(PseudoDbSet<Account>).FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(ct.Accounts.GetType().FullName);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, because all classes are correctly inherited.

In your code, something is wrong with the `DbSet` class from which `PseudoDbSet` inherits. Try to pull out `FullName` from the two types and compare them with full name of the `DbSet` type at the place where the downcast fails. In my example, these two types are the same and everything goes fine.

Comment: I found the problem. Actually, I used `DbSet<Account> accountSet = context.Set<Account>();` without overriding `Set<T>()` in the PseudoContext. Thanks!